# SELECT statement to get all columns from different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have multiple tables that begin with "PLAYERS_" and they consist of some data that I am trying to retrieve at once. I may add more tables in the future that begin with "PLAYER_" so I want to have a select statement that will get me all data of these tables without me selecting from all of these tables.

Here is a select statement that I am trying to use but I don't think its accurate:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'PLAYER_%';
```

All is this doing is getting me results of the subquery which is tables' info (not what I need). Is there an alternative way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

What I'm trying to achieve is the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM PLAYER_1, PLAYER_2, PLAYER_3;
```

But I want to do it in a way that I shouldn't worry about putting table names like that.

Comment: Fix your data model, so your players data is all in a single table, called, say, `players`.

Comment: Can't do that, each table is created for something else.

Comment: Do the tables all have the same columns?

Comment: Mostly yes, except for special columns for each table. But I am trying to these same columns.

Comment: Is there any player, that is in more than one table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, it is a poor design. You could still do something like this.

Assuming that you are selecting only the common columns from all the tables, you could create a dynamic view, which does a `UNION ALL` of all the existing player tables.

```
DECLARE
     v_select   CLOB;
BEGIN
     SELECT
          LISTAGG('SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM ' || table_name,' UNION ALL ' || CHR(10) ) WITHIN GROUP
          (
               ORDER BY table_name
          )
     INTO v_select
     FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'PLAYER_%';
     IF
          v_select IS NOT NULL
     THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_player_all as ' || v_select;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Then select from the view by executing the block(or put it into a procedure ) each time there's a new table added.

```
select * from v_player_all;
```

You may also join with `user_tab_columns` to dynamically select the common columns only.